# Returning .NET POCO as data frame over WebAPI to R client

Tags: c#, r, f#, deedle

I'm looking into how to *efficiently* return .NET Plain Old C# Objects (POCO) to R clients using WebAPI.  Right now we serialize JSON and the R client uses `httr` and `jsonfile`.

So far, we've successfully moved a lot of slow R calculations into .NET, and it seems like our remaining slowness is in serialization/deserialization and network overhead.  It would be ideal if we compressed the data on the .NET side of things using a format R could readily load, like `fst` (the fastest R de-serialization package).  However, I'm not an expert in R and don't know the `fst` file format.  I looked around and saw that F# has a `Deedle` library managing time series and interoperability with R, but don't think they specifically tackle this scenario.

This is for a data science framework, so I'm open to all kinds of suggestions here to further speed things up.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I am not sore if this is completely off topic but this one is definitely unclear. Do you want a fast single client way of sending the data over a good connection, or an efficient data transport for slow networks. When ever someone uses words like slow and fast is a sign that you don't have performance targets and optimization might just be useless once you test it in the real world.

Comment: I'm returning over a million data values to an R client.  I am interested in optimizing the total time it takes for me to calculate those values in .NET and be received by the R client.  As for the real world, this has been in production for about 6 months, and its expanding usage.  We've already eliminated a lot of R bottlenecks due to the fact that R's parallelism and concurrency features vary wildly by version of R and underlying operating system and even CPU manufacturer. We believe some of the best gains left are related to (de-)serialization of the data. What's not clear?

Comment: The question now at least makes more sense, but this is still too broad. There are many ways to achieve what your last comment explained, for example, you don't have to serialize those million values if you can stream them to the R side. If you could at least post your current R and C# code, that would help.

Comment: Efficiency is a terrible word to use here. Compression will always cost you in time it takes to do it and memory to buffer but will save you transport speed, So in scenarios where you don't have a lot of clients on a slow network it might be good thing to do, but if you have many concurrent clients it will be impossible to gzip or something similar. Fst reads seams to be optimized for reading from disk not network so sending the whole file might be good it depends on many things.

Comment: Feel free to lend your editorial pen to my questions so that the questions can be "as good as it can be".

Comment: Regarding compression, jsonfile is strictly slower than feather which is a columnar data store format based on Apache Arrow, and feather is strictly slower than fst which uses compression similar to that of kdb+ (fastest columnar data store database) but kdb+ uses proprietary compression for IPC over TCP/IP.

Comment: I would not be surprised if I granted a .NET Core WebApi site hosted on kestrel access to fst files and simply returned the raw fst file over http with gzipped chunked transfer encoding, wrote the response directly to disk as a raw fst file and then read it back in using fst package, that it will be faster than feather without compression.

Comment: Well that is a valid way of doing it just returning the whole data file as is and then writing it to disk on the client then using the optimizations fst has in regards to ssd reading. But this might be slower depending on the calculations you are doing, if your algorithm doesn't have a lot of random row access you could stream each row with out having to keep the whole file there it's really use case specific. I would recommend rewriting the question to include more specifics of your use case.

Comment: I literally don't know the use case (and don't care). People ask for a chocolate elephant, I ask them to describe to it to me, and I build it. I don't have to care that one use case is to eat it for Easter breakfast.  While knowing some use cases can allow for micro-optimizations, the maintenance cost for that is too high to justify the idiosyncrasies and cost of knowledge transfer if/when I ever leave the project. As a contractor, I have to deliver clean code that has low survival maintenance costs, as well as low enhancement costs for features that come after me.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few possibilities that might be of interest:

- You could use [RDotNet](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet) which lets you start and control R process from .NET. It provides API for evaluating R code and also inspecting and creating R data structures, so you could potentially avoid some of the overheads caused by serialization and WebAPI by more directly creating the R data frame and invoking R.
- Deedle has a plugin for the R type provider (which is based on RDotNet) and already comes with functionality for [R interop](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html) - this supports only some scenarios, but it might be worth looking into it.
- If you want to stick to serialization, then you can look into [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) which is an efficient binary serialization format for data frames with R and .NET bindings, so that might be faster than JSON, but still let you keep your current architecture.

Comment: Feel curious.  Your phrasing in your last bullet makes me think you question the current architecture. I've watched many of your talks on YouTube, and respect your opinion, and would not be surprised if you've blogged about some guidelines here in the past and/or made recommendations to Microsoft's data science teams. - I'll spend some time reading more of the nuances of Apache.Arrow csharp bindings and Flatbuffers which I've never used before.

Comment: I was thinking another option might be to take the raw C++ source code for fst, compile as a dll, and create C# bindings to the dll via P/Invoke.  But this might be too much of a lift for my tastes.  I'm not sure I'm ready to sign up to maintain a serialization protocol library.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I don't really have too detailed experience here - most of my work was not too performance-sensitive, so I was just trying to think and list some possible options. The way RDotNet works is that it loads R into the same .NET process via native interop, so it's sharing memory space - I think it's fairly likely that this will be faster than communication over WebAPI with serialization. The downside is that loading R in-process is pretty messy and breaks easily (while having a separate process is going to be more stable, but needs more serialization).

Comment: In any case, inner workings of R are pretty mysterious, so I would not be too suprirised if my "quite likely" guesses were all wrong. In any case, I think I'd probably try to do some quick comparison on RDotNet vs. WebAPI to see if that'd be better or not.